# JOIN Multiple Table based on timestamp and another condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, timestamp

I want to join 3 tables
which Table A have date and time in different field that need to be combined first so it can be compared on Table B using field timestamp.

Table A

```
 userid |  date_in   | check_in
--------+------------+----------
 145    | 2017-01-23 | 08:56:05
 254    | 2017-01-24 | 08:56:54
 202    | 2017-01-25 | 08:53:26
 15     | 2017-01-26 | 08:47:40
```

Table B

```
 userid |      checktime      |      sn
--------+---------------------+---------------
 145    | 2017-01-23 08:56:05 | 0345135200184
 254    | 2017-01-24 08:56:54 | 0345135200184
 202    | 2017-01-25 08:53:26 | 0345135200184
 15     | 2017-01-26 08:47:40 | 0345135200184
```

Table 3

```
      sn       |    alias
---------------+-------------
 0345135200184 | Alam Sutera
```

I tried this:

```
select process.userid, process.date_in, process.check_in, checkinout.checktime, iclock.alias from process 
inner join checkinout on checkinout.checktime=(select cast (date_in as timestamp(0)) + (check_in - time '00:00:00') checktime from process)
inner join iclock on checkinout.sn=iclock.sn
order by userid desc limit 10;
```

I also tried this:

```
select checkinout.userid, checkinout.checktime, checkinout.sn from checkinout
inner join lateral
(select distinct userid, date_in, check_in from process where 
date_in=(select checktime::date from checkinout) and 
check_in=(select checktime::time from checkinout)
order by date_in asc limit 1)
process ON true;
```

Both of them give error:
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Expected Result:

```
 userid |  date_in   | check_in |      checktime     | alias
--------+------------+----------+--------------------+-------
 145    | 2017-01-23 | 08:56:05 | 2017-01-21 09:49:04|Alam Sutera
 254    | 2017-01-24 | 08:56:54 | 2017-01-21 07:57:05|Alam Sutera
 202    | 2017-01-25 | 08:53:26 | 2017-01-21 14:27:00|Alam Sutera
 15     | 2017-01-26 | 08:47:40 | 2017-01-21 06:30:34|Alam Sutera
```

Can someone help me to solve this?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: how all `checktime` dates will be `2017-01-21` in your expected output. Please explain.

Comment: Owh, I am sorry. I mistake to edit the expected result. I mean it to be same with date_in. thanks for noticing it.

Comment: Owh, I am sorry. I mistake to edit the expected result. I mean it to be same with date_in. thanks for noticing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding `date` and `time` field you will get the timestamp which you can compare for join. so you can write your query like below:

```sql
select 
t1.userid, t1.date_in, t1.check_in, t2.checktime, t3.alias
from process t1
inner join checkinout t2 on t2. checktime= date_in + check_in and t1.userid=t2.userid
inner join table3 t3 on t2.sn=t3.sn
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=6fbd441ef2d24dd42cdf0039c867ab9a)

Regarding you error you have mentioned in your question `ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` is due to join condition you have used.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. It really solved. The date + time can be a timestamp as that.. I dunno about that.

Comment: t2.checktime= date_in + check_in and t1.userid=t2.userid

Do you know how can I use it in code igniter for this code?
I already tried this one:
$this->db->join ('checkinout t2', '(t2.checktime = date_in + check_in) and (t1.userid=t2.userid)');
but, still dont get the result expected just like in query above.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your separate Date and Time columns to a Timestamp using the To_Timestamp function as shown below.  This should enable you to join TableA and TableB as desired.

```
select * from tableA a 
join tableB b 
on a.userid = b.userid 
and to_timestamp(a.date_in || ' ' || a.check_in, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') = b.checktime
```

As demonstrated [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=fa07be9d440edc26f6c550d47d8c8678)